# Exchange Online, Retention policy flow?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

So I'm checking out an inherited O365/EXO config looking at retention policies and I've never seen one like this.. my question is: Am i understanding this correctly?

After 1 month the emails are move to Archive (thats obvious)
After 6 months they are deleted from Archive
Emails deleted after 6 months are available for recovery for another 6 months (Right??)
After being archived for 6 months emails are deleted?

Do I have this right judging by the image?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mailbox can apply one retention policy, one retention policy includes one or more retention tags: **[Apply a retention policy to mailboxes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/apply-retention-policy)**

Therefore, what kind of retention action depends on the **[retention tags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/retention-tags-and-policies#retention-tags)**, for retention tags, there are three types, they are:

- **Default policy tag (DPT)**: ***Automatically to entire mailbox***. A DPT applies to untagged items, which are mailbox items that don't have a
  retention tag applied directly or by inheritance from the folder.
- **Retention policy tag (RPT)**: ***Automatically to a default folder***. Default folders are folders created automatically in all mailboxes,
  for example: Inbox, Deleted Items, and Sent Items.
- **Personal tag**: ***Manually to items and folders***. Users can automate tagging by using Inbox rules to either move a message to a folder
  that has a particular tag or to apply a personal tag to the message.

For personal tag, users can apply a retention policy to user-created folders or subfolders and individual items (including subfolders and items in a default folder), but not to default folders(e.g. **Inbox**, **Sent Items**, **Deleted Items**). And you could select the personal tag in Outlook/OWA:

[image]

---

In your case, there are three kinds of retention tags:

DPT: **1 Month Move to Archive(Default)**, if you apply this retention policy **Support Inbox Policy** to mailboxes, it will work for items in folders which haven't been assigned other RPTs and PTs, after 30 days, it will move these items to archive .

RPT: **6 Month Delete(temporary recovery)** and **6 month delete from Archive**. The former will soft delete items in the Inbox folder 180 days later, the latter will delete(Maybe it is to permanently delete) the items in Archive after 180 days.

PT: **6 Month Delete**. It will delete items in user-created folders or subfolders and individual items (including subfolders and items in a default folder) after 180 days, and you need manually choose it in Outlook/OWA.

The relationships between the three retention tags are like the following:

[image]